# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}$ a simple extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5}):\mathbb{Q}$ a simple extension?

My conjecture is no, simply because I failed to come up with an $\alpha$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$; but then I struggle to deduce a contradiction by assuming $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$.

Proof:
Suppose $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$. It is obvious that $\alpha$ cannot be transcendental, hence $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}$ is a simple algebraic extension. Then $\mathbb{Q}[t]/<m>$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, where $m(t)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Also, if $deg(m)=n$, then $\{1, \alpha, ..., \alpha^{n-1}\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. Screeching halt.

Any hint would be appreciated-many thanks in advance! No solutions please.

Comment: @Snaw why didn't it pop up when I searched for the question...Thank you.

Comment: Dick, why don't you have a look at the right margin before posting? There the duplicate was already listed, under "Related".

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think you can only view the "Linked" and "Related" questions on the right margin after you post your question, which I admit, I have never bothered to check because I just assumed that all the similar questions will be shown in the "Similar Questions" box. I definitely will do that next time and hopefully will be quick enough to identify a good answer before the admins downvote my question.